# Coffeescript and variable check

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following code:

```
if variablename?
   alert "YES!"

l = []

if l[3]?
  alert "YES!"
```

It's translated into this:

```
var l;

if (typeof variablename !== "undefined" && variablename !== null) {
  alert("YESSS!");
}

l = [];

if (l[3] != null) {
  alert("YESSS!");
}
```

In Coffeescript, how would I express `l[3] !== "undefined"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `typeof` operator, like this:

```
if typeof l[3] != 'undefined'
  alert 'Yes!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware that `l[3] !== "undefined"` is asking whether `l[3]` is different from the string that says "undefined", not if its value isn't undefined. The comparison that CoffeeScript generates for `l[3]?` -> `l[3] != null` will verify when `l[3]` is some value different from undefined or null, which is what you want to ask most of the time :)